# How to formulate IF value_if_false to leave field as is

Tags: formula, operators

I have a field that is formulated to give me a day-count since a project has been created called "Study Age", written as such:

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Active"),
TODAY () - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate),
Null
)
```

I could not find a way for this formula to keep the final number in tact once the status was changed, so I then created a separate field to track the final number called "Days Study Active", but I am having trouble keeping the number in that field.

The formula below is the closest I can get to making it work:

```
IF(Ready_to_Invoice__c = true && Study_Age__c > 0 , Study_Age__c , null )
```

This formula will show the number once the "Ready to Invoice" box is checked, but returns a null as soon as the Study Age field is cleared (when the status is changed to Invoiced). I tried using a `!=null` operator rather than the `>0`, but that operation does not fill in the number at all when "Ready to Invoice" is checked.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to keep the final number in the `Study Age` field (and get rid of the second field), but if that is not possible, some help to transfer that number to the additional field would be great.

Answer (score 1):

So, the first thing to remember is that formulas are always calculated at runtime. They act exactly like formulas do in Excel. If the input data to the formula changes, the formula field is recalculated when the value of the formula field is required

So, you're going to need three dates:

- `TODAY()`
- `CreatedDate`
- `Ready_To_Invoice_Date__c` (a date field, not a formula field)

And your formula becomes:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Active"),TODAY () - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate),
IF(Ready_to_Invoice__c, TODAY() - Ready_To_Invoice_Date__c,
   NULL)
)
```

You are going to need a Flow, Process Builder, Workflow Rule or Apex trigger to stamp the record's `Raedy_to_Invoice_Date__c` with the current date once `Ready_to_Invoice__c` becomes checked